# How to change labels of references to letters?

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to change the labels of references to alphabetic characters. such as

```
[a] authors, article.
```

How can I achieve this goal in latex without labeling each reference by hand for each item using, e.g., **\bibitem[a]**?

Furthermore, the counter *alph* cannot exceed 26, it would be nice if the answer to my question can also solve this problem such that the 27th is *aa*, the 28th is *bb*, and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `alphalph` packages will produce counters of this form.  You can incorporate these in to the bibliography mechanism by redefining `\@bibitem` and `\@biblabel`:

[image: Sample cite]

[image: Sample bib]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph,cite}

\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\bibcite{#1}{\alphalph{\value{\@listctr}}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{[\alphalph{#1}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}\cite{phdthesis-minimal}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

From the comment, you say you also want to apply this a standalone `thebibliography` environment, where there is a second such environment present.
This can be achieved by moving the commands in the preamble inside the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph,cite}

\begin{document}
\cite{a2,x28}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{a1} Source.
\bibitem{a2} Source.
\bibitem{a3} Source.
\end{thebibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\bibcite{#1}{\alphalph{\value{\@listctr}}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{[\alphalph{#1}]}
\makeatother
\bibitem{x1} Reference.
\bibitem{x2} Reference.
\bibitem{x3} Reference.
\bibitem{x4} Reference.
\bibitem{x5} Reference.
\bibitem{x6} Reference.
\bibitem{x7} Reference.
\bibitem{x8} Reference.
\bibitem{x9} Reference.
\bibitem{x10} Reference.
\bibitem{x11} Reference.
\bibitem{x12} Reference.
\bibitem{x13} Reference.
\bibitem{x14} Reference.
\bibitem{x15} Reference.
\bibitem{x16} Reference.
\bibitem{x17} Reference.
\bibitem{x18} Reference.
\bibitem{x19} Reference.
\bibitem{x20} Reference.
\bibitem{x21} Reference.
\bibitem{x22} Reference.
\bibitem{x23} Reference.
\bibitem{x24} Reference.
\bibitem{x25} Reference.
\bibitem{x26} Reference.
\bibitem{x27} Reference.
\bibitem{x28} Reference.
\bibitem{x29} Reference.
\bibitem{x30} Reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If you want to do this with an external database, then you could use the `multibib` package and make similar adjustments local to the one bibliography.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. In fact, I have additional requirement, which was not specified in the post, sorry for that. I in fact need also the normal reference numeric labels. That is, in some part, I need the alphabetic and in the other part I need numeric. Thus, what I want most is a new *thebibliography* environment, call it *thebibliographyalph* for instance. How would your suggestion be translated into such an environment?

Comment: @AndrewSwann if ones uses hyperref package, the citation number will be redefined to Arabic number!!!

Comment: @SayOL That is a standard problem with `hyperref` and modifications to the bibliography commands.  A work around is to load `hyperref` with `implicit=false`, but then many hyperlinks are simply not created.  Otherwise one has to write commands that are modelled on `hyperref`'s versions of `\@bibitem` and `\@biblabel`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new answer, it is just something too long to be left as comment.

In the comments to the [great answer of Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254512/128737), there is the discussion about how to proceed not to break the `hyperref` behaviour. Since I had exactly this need when I came here, I decided to leave what I did as a possible patch for other users.

**Desclaimer:** It is quick and dirty, use it with a pinch of salt. Actually, here it is just about putting a prefix to the full bibliography, but anyone can use this as a starting point for her/his needs.

---

Looking at how the `\@bibitem` is redefined in the `hyperref` command,

```
\def\@bibitem#1{%
    \@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
      \hyper@anchorstart{cite.#1\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
    }%
    \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}%
```

it should not be so hard to insert a prefix into the `\bibcite` call. Of course, this has to go together with a redefinition of `\@biblabel` as also shown by Andrea Swann.

Then I decided to create a `changeBibPrefix` command in order to redefine correctly the needed macros.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\changeBibPrefix}[1]{%
  \def\@bibitem##1{%
    \@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
      \hyper@anchorstart{cite.##1\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
    }%
    \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\bibcite{##1}{#1\the\value{\@listctr}}%
      }%
    \endgroup
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
  }
  \def\@biblabel##1{[#1##1]}
}
\makeatother
```

The only thing to pay attention here is to use `#1` to identify the prefix passed to the `\changeBibPrefix` command and `##1` to identify the `\@bibitem` or `\@biblabel` macro argument.

At this point one can put all together in an example, where I decided to make the number in the bibliography continue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, citecolor = blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{bibIndex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\changeBibPrefix}[1]{%
  \def\@bibitem##1{%
    \@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
      \hyper@anchorstart{cite.##1\@extra@b@citeb}\relax\hyper@anchorend
    }%
    \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\protect\noexpand
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\bibcite{##1}{#1\the\value{\@listctr}}%
      }%
    \endgroup
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
  }
  \def\@biblabel##1{[#1##1]}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-3] Cite \cite{ref1} and cite \cite{ref2}. \lipsum[2]

\changeBibPrefix{P}
\renewcommand{\refname}{First bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{ref1} First reference
    \bibitem{ref2} Second reference
    \setcounter{bibIndex}{\value{enumiv}}
\end{thebibliography}

\section{Some other section}
\lipsum[1] Cite \cite{ref1} and cite \cite{ref3}. \lipsum[2-5]

\changeBibPrefix{R}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Second bibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \setcounter{enumiv}{\value{bibIndex}}
    \bibitem{ref3} Third reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```