# How to add a letter before the number of citation in the text?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I want `\cite` to give me [A1] in the text.  I cited the reference here `\cite{ref1}`, which gives the reference as [1].
    How to modify it to give me [A1] with A prefixing the number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

I cited the reference here \cite{ref1}, which gives the reference as [1].
How to modify it to give me [A1] with A prefixing the number.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ref1} name. 2017 Title of the reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For *that* specific reference? Or do you want *all* references to start with a A?

Comment: Hi, @  José Carlos Santos, all reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `\@bibitem` and `\@biblabel`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@bibitem[1]{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
    {\string\bibcite{#1}{A\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}% <------------
\def\@biblabel#1{[A#1]}% <-------------------
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    I cited the reference here \cite{ref1}, \cite{sec}.

    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem{ref1} name. 2017 Title of the reference.
        \bibitem{sec} name. 2017 Title of the reference.
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just in case you loaded `hyperref` and you wonder why the links do not work as expected, you can have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452462/128737).