# Insert letter before citation with biblatex/biber only in one `refsection`

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to insert a letter (eg. "S") before citations both in text and in the bibliography. I've found a similar question here:

[How to add a letter before the number of citation in the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381114/how-to-add-a-letter-before-the-number-of-citation-in-the-text)

However:

- I want to do it for only a `refsection`,
- with the using of `biblatex`/`biber`.

But I have no idea how. My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none,backref=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Considered as refsection 0}
This is a normal citation: \cite{NiInt_3}.

\section{Refsection1}
\begin{refsection}
I want to cite this \cite{NiInt_1} as [S1] here and in the bibliography.

\printbibliography[keyword=withletter, title={With letter}]
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography[title={Without letter}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=S]` in a refcontext:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{lamport1994latex,
    title={LATEX: a document preparation system: user's guide and reference manual},
    author={Lamport, Leslie},
    year={1994},
    publisher={Addison-wesley}
  }
  @book{mittelbach2004latex,
    title={The LATEX companion},
    author={Mittelbach, Frank and Goossens, Michel and Braams, Johannes and Carlisle, David and Rowley, Chris},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley Professional}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[sorting=none,backref=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Considered as refsection 0}
This is a normal citation: \cite{mittelbach2004latex}.

\section{Refsection1}

\begin{refsection}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=S]
I want to cite this \cite{lamport1994latex} as [S1] here and in the bibliography.

\printbibliography[title={With letter}]
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography[title={Without letter}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've just copy-pasted your answer, but does not work: every citation is preceded by "S". Do you have any idea, what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you run the MWE unchanged?

Comment: Yes. Just copy-paste, pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex.

Comment: Curious. Are you running an up to date system?

Comment: I think so. I have installed texlive packages about 2 years ago together with the OS (Opensuse 15.1).

Comment: Try installing a more recent version of [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) (you might also be interested in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/29873)

Comment: I have updated `Texlive` and now it works. Thank you for your kind help!