# How to change labels of references to the letter "A" followed by number?

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to change the labels of references to the letter "A" followed by numbers, e.g.

```
[A1] Authors, Paper name
[A2] Autrors, Paper name
```

I have already read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254501/how-to-change-labels-of-references-to-letters) but I did'nt understand how to change it according to my needs. I also need to do this inside of *thebibliography* environment because the template that I am using do not accept bibtex external files.

Edit:

I continued to try changing the answer of the question that I linked here and managed to do that:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\bibcite{#1}{\alphalph{\value{\@listctr}}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{[A{#1}]}
\makeatother

\bibitem{Test} Author1, Title1

\bibitem{Test2} Author2, Title2

\end{thebibliography}
```

Which resulted in:

[image]

But inside the text the citation still not change

```
Example of citation \cite{Test}.
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. I also typed in the answer below that is marked "correct" but it does not fix my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your preamble write:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\bibcite{#1}{A\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{[A{#1}]}
\makeatother
```

The redefinition of `\@bibitem` changes the item in the bibliography, the `{A\the\value{\@listctr}}` sets the label for `\cite`.

Comment: Answer written above does not fix my problem either. See edit from OP who still runs into the same problem.