# Bibliography style: Author-name in square bracket in references list

Tags: bibliographystyle

May I know how I can achieve the bibliography style shown in the second image? I have already found online a way to cite with square bracket authoryear format but my reference list looks like the one below:

[image]

I need it to look like this.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: [Check this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419830/how-to-change-labels-of-references-to-the-letter-a-followed-by-number). You can customize the content inside the square brackets

Comment: If you use biblatex, then you can customize the labels with [\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68862/biblatex-alphabetic-style-like-smith-2005)

Comment: Thanks @DominikKern