# Is there any reference list style like this? What is it called?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, bibliographystyle

I am new to latex and academic writing. I have encountered latex doing this with just \bibliographystyle{apalike} and bibliography{}. I think I have seen this [author, year] style in the reference list before. I am not sure. Note: I have not put up any in-text citations. Is there any style that does this? What is it called? And if not why does latex do it? btw it's done with bibtex[image] I have taken the image from another question posted here a month ago: [Bibliography style: Author-name in square bracket in references list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661453/bibliography-style-author-name-in-square-bracket-in-references-list)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I think the output you show is not only due to the use of the `apalike` bibliography style but, importantly, to a failure to use a citation management package such as `apalike` or `natbib`. The underlining, on the other hand, is most likely due to the [ulem](https://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package being loaded without the option `normalem`. Given that at least two questionable decisions had to be made to arrive at the result shown in the screenshot, I wouldn't recommend emulating this "look".

Comment: Thank you. For the quick response. Yes, I don't like it either. I thought since there weren't any errors maybe it was some sort of reference style that I didn't know of . Anyway, thanks for the clarification. I'll try and figure out what can be done. Thank you.